# Custom HttpAttribute Validation when override IsValid(object value) is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

Hi I have this custom validation but with a little diferences at the type of the property to validate and always even if I if  meet business rules the value of ModelState is "null" =s ...here's some code

Model

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(TypeName = "image")]
        [ValidateFile(Allowed = new string[] { ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg" },
                      MaxLength = 1024 * 1024 * 3,
                      ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG , JPEG , JPG image smaller than 3MB")]
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

===========

ValidateFileAtribute

```
public class ValidateFileAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public string[] Allowed { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object **value**)
    {


        var Photo = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (Photo == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (Photo.ContentLength > MaxLength)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!Allowed.Contains(Photo.FileName.Substring(Photo.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'))))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

HERE'S WHERE VALUE SHOULD NOT BE NULL!!

Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Restaurant</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Photo)
        </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Photo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo)
        <input name="ImageFile" type="file" id="ImageFile"  />
      </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your property:

```
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

In the attribute:

```
var Photo = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
```

This will be always null. Try:

```
var Photo = value as byte[]
```

Of course you have to fix the addtional parts of your validation logic.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I did try what you posted and fix some logic but still value gets null even when I change var Photo = value as byte[]

Comment: Then you isn't assigning anything to the Photo property.

Answer (score 0):

I would check what you place in byte[] Photo, as I have noticed that when the data going in is not valid, the 'object value' is null.

One example is that for datatype of int, when i enter 2147483647, 'object value' does contain the 2147483647.

When I enter 2147483648, the value parameter contains 0 as the largest positive integer value is 2147483647.

**Update 7/5/13**

You need to change your datatype to "HttpPostedFileBase"

> public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }

instead of "byte[]"

> public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

There should be no need for

> [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(TypeName = "image")]

Your

> (object **value**)

should now contain the System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper which contains the file to be uploaded.

This goes hand in hand with what I wrote before, that you will get a **null** if the data type coming in is not of the correct type.

Comment: right so how can make the image I;m trying to upload will be VALID?

Comment: I updated my answer above. Let me know if you get it to work.